# print float up to four place on either side

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I am newbie, I am trying to print an `float` value upto four place on either side. For example `11.3` will be `0011.3000`. For this I am using following line:-

```
float t = 11.3;
printf("%4.4f", t);
```

But I am getting `11.3000`. So, is it even possible what i am trying to do? If yes then how?  Thanks

Comment: `%04.4f`, iirc, produces leading zeroes

Comment: @collapsar, no that doesn't work

Comment: not working bro

Comment: `%09.4f` might work better. The 9 means "print in a field 9 characters wide"

Comment: Fist number is the total size of the field while the second is the precision. What you want would be "%09.4f".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `f` is incorrect in your code fragment, it should be `float` or `double`.

To produce leading zeroes, use the `0` `printf` modifier and specify the minimum width expected, 9 characters in your example (4 places before the `.` plus the `.` plus 4 more places after the `.`).

The format is therefore `%09.4f`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double t = 11.3;
    printf("%09.4f\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0001.3000
```

Note however that if the number is negative, you will only get 3 places before the `.` and if the number is too large in absolute value (<= `-999.99995` or >= `9999.99995`), the output will have more than 9 characters. If you mean to have 4 places before the `.` for negative values too, you should use `% 010.4f`: the number will then be prefixed with a space if positive and a `-` if negative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double t = 11.3;
    printf("%09.4f\n", t);
    printf("% 010.4f\n", t);
    printf("% 010.4f\n", -t);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0011.3000
 0011.3000
-0011.3000
```

Comment: Thanks sir, But no need for double. At-least in my case float is also working

Comment: @TabishSaifullah:  You can declare `f` as `float` if you wish without any other modification. Yet using `float` does not save much: `float` values are converted to `double` when passed to `printf` anyway. They have much less precision and are not faster than `double` except on embedded systems with low computing power. If your platform is a regular PC, I advise to use `double` for all floating point calculations.

Comment: @chqrlie: There are a variety of circumstances in which `float` performance is faster than `double` on modern general-purpose processors. Division and square root are typically faster even if addition, subtraction, and multiplication are the same. Library routines such as cosine and logarithm are typically faster in the `float` versions than in `double`. Code that is vectorized manually or automatically may be twice as fast in `float`. In turn, this means routines such as FFTs, BLAS, or other array-processing routines will be faster. And, of course, memory copying is faster with smaller data.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the format spec is the width of the field you are printing in, not the number of digits before the decimal place. Your desired output has 9 characters in it, zero padded on the left, so do

```
float t = 11.3;
printf("%09.4f", t);
```

This might break down if for example the integer part of your number gets too big  For a finer level of control, work with integers:

```
float t = 11.3;
int i, f;
i = (int)t;
f = (int)((t - i) * 10000 + 0.5);
printf("%04d.%04d", i, f);
```

All this assumes positive numbers. Neither example shown here will work properly with negatives.

Comment: I'm afraid your integer code does not work for negative values, and rounds values differently from `%09.4f`

Comment: @chqrlie Fixed :)

Comment: Not completely: `0.00006` will print as `0000.0000` with your integer code and `0000.0001` with the `%09.4f` format.

Comment: @chqrlie added rounding.

Comment: That's better, but the default rounding method in C is not necessarily `FE_UPWARD`. For example both `printf("%09.4f\n", 0.00045F);` produces `0000.0004`. your rounding code produces `0000.0005`. Floating point to string conversion is a **very difficult** subject.

Answer (score 2):

```
float t = 11.3;
printf("%4.4f", t);
```

In your code above **4 before .** means total number of characters to be printed.
and **4 after .** mean number of characters after decimal.
Since you want xxxx.xxxx hence you should write it like:

```
printf("%9.4f", t);
```